# Check if all required inputs are filled and submit form automatically

Tags: jquery, forms

In my form I want that when all required fields (`.required-entry`) are filled, automatically submit form without clicking on submit button.

```
<div id="billing-form">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="field form-group">
            <input type="text" class="input-text form-control required-entry" id="name" />
        </div>
        <div class="field form-group">
            <input type="text" class="input-text form-control required-entry" id="mid-name" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div class"button-container">
    <button type="button" title="Continue" id="btn-continue" class="button btn-continue" onclick="billing.save()">Continue</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. What if I make a typo in one of the fields and it loses focus? I will have no chance to correct the mistake.

Comment: Thats not a better idea to submit the form when the required field are filled. Please give some time to user to review the details

Comment: Yes you are right, but I need this only for validate and make visible the second form ( in same page ). You can edit after the fields. When all form is complete, you can click on submit button. This form is only one of four step.

Comment: @user3309614 Is my answer useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad idea to sumbit form when inputs is fill, but you can show next form when current forms inputs is filled. For this purpose use this code.

```js
$("#form1 input").on("keyup change", function(){
    var inputValidate = true;
    $("#form1 input").each(function(index, element){     
        if ($(element).val() == "")
           inputValidate = false;
    });
    
    if (inputValidate)
        $("#form2").show();
    else
        $("#form2").hide();
});
```

```css
#form2 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">     
    <div>
        <label>Form 1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Lastname</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</form>
<br />
<form id="form2">     
    <div>
        <label>Form 2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Birthday</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Country</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</form>
```